using kotlin multiplatform with smtp to send email
I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project and need to send an email in the background. The functionality should be triggered from the shared code. I have implemented an SMTP email sender in iOSMain, but the email is not being sent. I am unsure if the issue is with my code or the server configuration.
The code I used connects to the SMTP server, authenticates with an app password, and attempts to send an email. However, I don’t see any errors or email deliveries. Could someone help me identify what might be wrong or provide guidance on debugging this?
Here is the code I’ve written:
`  actual suspend fun sendEmail(
smtpHost: String,
smtpPort: Int,
username: String,
password: String,
from: String,
to: String,
subject: String
): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
try {
val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp()
.connect(hostname = smtpHost, port = smtpPort)
        socket.use {
            val input = socket.openReadChannel()
            val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

            // Add the logging version of readResponse
            suspend fun readResponse(): String {
                val response = input.readUTF8Line() ?: throw Exception("SMTP server response missing")
                println("SMTP Response: $response") // Log the server response
                return response
            }

            // Handshake with the SMTP server
            output.writeStringUtf8("HELO $smtpHost\r\n")
            readResponse()`

